# Reproduce encrypting method in Java

Tags: javascript, java, c#, encryption, aes

I have wrote two functions to decrypt and encrypt messages in C# and Javascript, but I need it also in Java and I can't get it to work the same as in previous ones.

JS encrypting method:

```
this.aesEncrypt = function (encryptedMessage) {
    var key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    var initialVector = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    var encryptedText = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(encryptedMessage, key,
    {
        iv: initialVector,
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
    });
    return encryptedText.toString().hexEncode();
}
String.prototype.hexEncode = function () {
    var hex, i;

    var result = "";
    for (i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        hex = this.charCodeAt(i).toString(16);
        result += ("0" + hex).slice(-2);
    }

    return result;
}
```

C# decrypting method:

```
private static string AesDecrypt(string encryptedMessage)
{
    try
    {
        var temp = FromHex(encryptedMessage);
        var encryptedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(temp));
        var aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider
        {
            BlockSize = 128,
            KeySize = 256,
            Mode = CipherMode.CBC,
            Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7,
            Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"),
            IV = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
        };
        var crypto = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);
        var secret = crypto.TransformFinalBlock(encryptedBytes, 0, encryptedBytes.Length);
        crypto.Dispose();
        return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(secret);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return null;
    }
}

public static byte[] FromHex(string hex)
{
    hex = hex.Replace("-", "");
    var raw = new byte[hex.Length / 2];
    for (var i = 0; i < raw.Length; i++)
    {
        raw[i] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16);
    }
    return raw;
}
```

Java encrypting method:

```
public static String toHex(String arg) {
    return String.format("%x", new BigInteger(1, arg.getBytes()));
}
public static String AesEncrypt(String encryptedMessage){
    try {
        IvParameterSpec initialVector = new IvParameterSpec("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx".getBytes("UTF-8"));
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx".getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, initialVector);

        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(encryptedMessage.getBytes());
        StringBuilder encryptedSb = new StringBuilder(encrypted.length);
        for (byte i : encrypted){
            encryptedSb.append(i);
        }
        return toHex(encryptedSb.toString());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Java returns 80 hexa-digits after encryption and JS returns 48 hexa-digits.
AFAIK Java PKCS5 padding is the same as C# PKCS7 padding.

I have also tried using base64 encoding of the result using
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/download_codec.cgi
, but it's still not this.

```
public static String AesEncrypt(String encryptedMessage){
    try {
        IvParameterSpec initialVector = new IvParameterSpec("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx".getBytes("UTF-8"));
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx".getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, initialVector);

        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(encryptedMessage.getBytes());

        byte[] base64 = Base64.encodeBase64(encrypted);

        StringBuilder encryptedSb = new StringBuilder(base64.length);
        for (byte i : base64){
            encryptedSb.append(i);
        }
        return toHex(encryptedSb.toString());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this just for fun? You basically never want to implement your own encryption algorithms.

Comment: Which Java provider are you using?

Comment: @Michael, I am not implementing my own algorithm. I am using AES CBC with PKCS7 Padding

Comment: @Keith, I'm building it on Android device

Comment: This is not my area of expertise but could it be a UTF8 issue? I don't think Javascript can handle true UTF8/ Hex on it's own. If this is the case maybe something like this will help: https://github.com/mathiasbynens/utf8.js

Comment: @Blizzardengle, JS method works fine, and CryptoJS probably handles itself UTF8 coding

Comment: How big is your plaintext?

Comment: @Keith, for test it is "abc" but for normal events it is different, can even be hundret of characters

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I forgot about encoding to Base64. I was almost there in recent question edit. I just forgot about `Base64.encodeBase64String` which didn't actually work, but I took a look at implementation of this function in `Base64` class and I've found how to do it more explicit.

```
public static String AesEncrypt(String encryptedMessage){
    try {
        IvParameterSpec initialVector = new IvParameterSpec("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx".getBytes("UTF-8"));
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx".getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, initialVector);

        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(encryptedMessage.getBytes());
        String base64 = StringUtils.newStringUtf8(Base64.encodeBase64(encrypted, false));

        return toHex(base64);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: See my post below. Use the `DatatypeConverter`. It's has static one-liners to convert encodings.

Comment: I can't import `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter`

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: Right. So , like I said, copy paste it's _business logic_ to ensure you are encoding the same way it does.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of any other parameters, AES operates on 16-byte blocks. PCKS#5 padding in Java AES will resolve to [PCKS#7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7). With PCKS#7, you are padding to the block boundary; i.e., padding up to the nearest 16 bytes.

Your UTF-8 input "ABC" is 3 bytes. 16 bytes will require *(16–3)=13* bytes of padding. Therefore, the ciphertext will be 16 bytes, or 32 hex characters.

That all said, I believe something is wrong with your encoding conversions between your `StringBuilder` and `toHex()` logic. Try using [`DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(byte[] val)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html) to convert `byte[] encrypted` back into hex.